# Getting DIV's and the content within them to scale to the browser size?

Tags: html, css

At the moment I am having trouble trying to get my website to scale proportionally to the browser size.

For example the first image within the main container on my page is defined by

```
<div class = "container">
<div class ="titlecontainer"><img src="../img/topleft_title.jpg" alt="TopLeftTitle" / </div> </div>
```

Which uses the CSS

```
.container {
    width: 1920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative
}
.titlecontainer {
    max-width: 960px;
    max-height: 107;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    size:relative
}
```

I have been told that perhaps using % (percentage) rather than px (pixels) to define my max-width and max-height might resolve the situation but having tried and tested this method I am yet to receive any results. If you could offer any help with regards to this problem I would very much appreciate it, if you require any further information please let me know.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle too?

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/8arntozr/) a jsfiddle. I just used some random picture's URL I found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding width:100% and/or height:100%? Put them onto your container's css

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem to make a difference, thank you for taking the time to comment though I appreciate it.